# Cross out the selected text using macro script in TexStudio

Tags: macros, texstudio

I have a Tex file that I need to edit while somehow keeping the original words and sentences highlighted. To do this, I am going to cross out the part of the original text that I replace with my own words. The command `\st{TEXT}` in the package `soul` seems to do the job. I'm looking for a way to define a macro in TeXstudio such that by selecting the text, the cross out command encapsulate the text, i.e. `\st{THE_SELECTED_TEXT}`. I am not familiar with macro programming in TeXstudio.

Comment: Does it need to be a TeXstudio macro? TeXstudio kind of can this on its own if the macro `\st` is known for it. If you select text and then type `\st` and auto-complete it TeXstudio automatically places the selected text as an argument to `\st`. The only problem is that `\st` may not properly recognized by TeXstudio. The `soul.cwl` (the auto-complete configuration file) lists it as a parameter-less macro so you might either change that or use your own `soul-custom.cwl` file or actually simply ad `\st{arg}` as a macro. Also, TeXstudio scans `\newcommand` and `\providecommand´ (dummy) entries.

Comment: I check-marked `soul.cwl` in the configuration of TeXstudio, but it didn't help me. Thanks for your comment. It solved my problem

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how you'd do it with a script:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

I have found another quite simple solution.
Say, if you have just typed `$AB$`, and then you want to surround `AB` by `\overline{}`. You can select the text `AB` and then directly type "ov"(you may, of course, find that the word AB is deleted, but don't worry!) and press
 "Tab", then you can get what you want.

The macro:

[image]