# Macro in texstudio/texmaker to surround selected text with tags

Tags: macros, texstudio

When you use some of the predefined shortcuts in texstudio on selected text, it wraps the text with the appropriate tags(is that the proper term?). For instance, suppose i highlight `Hello World`and press Ctrl+i it becomes `\textit{Hello World}`.

That is pretty handy as you dont't have to move the end tags around. I was wondering whether there a way to program macro to have similar behavior too. Many thanks in advanced.

[edit] found a similar answered question: [Cross out the selected text using macro script in TexStudio](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122296/cross-out-the-selected-text-using-macro-script-in-texstudio)

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for the suggestion! I managed to find a similar question and answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/122296/cross-out-the-selected-text-using-macro-script-in-texstudio) For reference, here is how the script would look like.

```
%SCRIPT
txt = cursor.selectedText()
editor.write("\\underline{"+txt+"}")
cursor.clearSelection()
```

Answer (score 5):

In Texmaker you can use **user tags** to achieve this.

1. Go to the *Menu User > User Tags > Edit User Tags*
2. On the left hand side select a free slot (e.g. Menu 1:)
3. On the right hand side enter any name for the macro in the *Menu Item* Textbox (e.g. Bold)
4. In the Latex Content box enter your code (e.g. **\textbf{@}**)

[image]

The @-symbols are placeholders. The first @-symbol is replaced by the currently selected text when inserting the user tag.

Now i can just select the text i want to be surrounded and press **Shift+F1** or select the appropriate tag from the menu. (F1 because it is the first entry in my case, shortcuts are shown in the menu.)

For more information check out this: [Texmaker Documentation: User Tags](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION33)

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the macro programming functions of the mentioned editors but I use [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/)-Scripts for this, which should work in all editors. The following is just one example.

```
F2::
Send ^c
Send \textbf{{}{}}{LEFT}
Send ^v
Return
```

Comment: Ok for Windows users... but... me and many many people do not want to pay something so expensive and so buggy to M$ anymore.

Comment: Well, there is Autokey under Linux, Textexpander under Mac OS, Emacs can do it as well...