# Quick conversion of a selected item to math mode

Tags: math-mode, texmaker, editors

I am using Texmaker 4.5. How to quick enter the math mode delimiters ($ $) for a selected items. The "in-line math" environment with the "$...$" button in the toolbar (shortcut : Ctrl+Alt+M) helps only to place it after creating the envt "$...$".

Comment: You can do this with User Tags.  See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/303033/2693) for details. (Not a duplicate question though.)